# How to disable pasting in a gradio textbox

Tags: python, textbox, paste, gradio

How do I disable pasting (ctrl + v or other) in a [Gradio](https://www.gradio.app/) Textbox in Python?

Setting the `interactive` parameter to `False` makes the textbox uneditable, which is not what I want.

I tried to write my own textbox in html and use `gradio.HTML`, but then I lose all kind of interactivity between blocks. I understand `gradio.HTML` is meant to display HTML, not to communicate with other Gradio elements.

I tried to use the `js` argument in the `gradio.Textbox.change` method, in order to handle the event with javascript. However, the event itself is not exposed, only the text value itself that changed. Basically I can only apply a function which takes a string as argument. There is the same issue with the `fn` argument which allows to call a Python function.

I tried to wrap a `gradio.Textbox` in a custom class, so that I could call `gradio.Textbox.change` and be able to have the current input string, but also the string before the change. Then I apply some hardcoded rule (basically if the new string is too different from the old one, it means there was pasting). In the `gradio.Textbox.change`, the `gradio.Textbox` is both the input and the output, where my rule is basically `if not pasting then return new_input else return old_input`.

This last solution is the closest I could get. It has a massive drawback though: after every input change (so every time the user presses a key), the focus is lost. I understand it is not possible to set the focus to a specific `gradio.Textbox`. A solution would be to put an invisible `gradio.Textbox` output, that would be kind of my hidden real input. But this solution is not great because if the user types too fast, the event handling is not done by the next input change, which causes issues.